# returning rows satisfying multiple conditions for a column from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table with hospitals and treatments(associated with sub treatments) that they provide. I need to make mysql query on the table which returns hospitals providing all treatment/sub_treatment given in a list. For example:

From table below I need hospitals providing all treatments in list: (tretament_id, sub_treatment_id) =  (1-1, 1-2). So result must be hospitals with id 1 and 8.

```
    hospital_id   |  treatment_id | sub_treatment_id
    -------------------------------------------------
    1             |             1 |                1
    1             |             1 |                2    
    1             |             1 |                3
   _________________________________________________
    4             |             1 |                1
    4             |             2 |                1
   _________________________________________________
    8             |             1 |                1
    8             |             1 |                2
   _________________________________________________
    7             |             2 |                1
```

I tried WHERE IN but it works like OR so returns hospital 4 which satisfies only (1,1). How can I write an sql query like WHERE IN but which works like AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT hospital_id
FROM mytable
WHERE (treatment_id, sub_treatment_id) IN ((1, 1), (1, 2))
GROUP BY hospital_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN (treatment_id, sub_treatment_id) IN ((1, 1), (1, 2)) 
                THEN 1 
             END) = 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a062a/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select hospital_id
from t
where treatment_id = 1 and sub_treatment_id in (1, 2)
group by hospital_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that there are no duplicates in the table.  That is easy enough to fix using `count(distinct)`, but probably not necessary.

Comment: It seems like this query have limitations in "where treatment_id=1". because  list is dynamic, it can be (1-1, 1-2, 3-4, 4-2 ..etc..).

Comment: @zenwarrior . . . That particular `where` clause seemed the easiest way to express the conditions in your question.  Obviously, you would need to change the `where` clause for other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `JOIN`:

```
select distinct t.hospital_id
from hospitals h and treatments t ON h.id = t.hospital_id
having GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t.treatment_id, '-', t.sub_treatment_id)
                    ORDER BY t.treatment_id, t.sub_treatment_id) 
                    = '1-1,1-2';
```